# What is output_projection argument in embedding_rnn_seq2seq model in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, decode, encode

As I read the API it says we can keep above argument None or setting up to the weight parameter of the output layer. What is this thing doing ?

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_seq2seq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a partial explanation in the [seq2seq tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq#sampled_softmax_and_output_projection). The short explanation is that it allows an efficient approximation of the loss when there are huge numbers of classes (via [sampled_softmax_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss)).

Comment: I'm a little confused by the partial explanation.  I understand how one would use the weights/biases to perform sampled_softmax_loss, but I still don't see how to actually use the flag in the API.  Are there any tutorials that show the output_projection actually being used?

Comment: Please see my question on another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716295/how-to-use-output-projection-weights-biases-in-seq2seq